# Is there a quantitative way to compare the distribution shape of different samples?

Tags: distributions, data-visualization, nonparametric

I am conducting some research which involves visually/graphically observing the differences between the shapes of the distributions of different samples.

I would like to automate this process (at least somewhat), so that I can scale the number of samples I look at (as well as speeding things up, reducing human error etc.).

Is there a way to *quantitatively describe/measure the shape of a distribution* so that comparisons between shapes can be made algorithmically?

Comment: univariate or multivariate sample?

Comment: Interested readers, and potential respondents, would like to know precisely what you mean by a "sample" and by the "shape" of a distribution. One reply already posted assumes a sample is a collection of $p$-tuples of real numbers and that "shape" is a similarity-invariant description of the resulting point cloud in $p$ dimensions. Many others, though, would take a "sample" to be a collection of *numbers,* its distribution to be their *empirical distribution function,* and its "shape" to be a description of the EDF up to changes of scale and location. Those are very different interpretations!

Comment: @whuber: alleluia! (i.e. thanks for formulating the comment so clearly).

Comment: @user603: univariate sample

Comment: @whuber: A few clarification of the terms I used in my question: By _sample_, I am referring to a collection of numbers. The samples don't all have the same number of points (which may complicate things further). By _distribution_, I am referring to the **EDF**, and by _shape_ I am referring to a metric (ideally encapsulated by a single number), that captures measures of central tendency and dispersion.

Comment: OK, that's clear enough. But I need to ask this, since conventionally the "shape" of a distribution concerns all of its characteristics *except* central tendency and dispersion: since you're focusing on these two parameters alone, aren't you really just asking how one can estimate them from a sample (such as a mean and SD or a median and MAD)?

Comment: @whuber: My meaning of _shape_ in my question, differs from the description you gave. I use _shape_ in layman's terms as opposed to a statistical context. I was not aware there would be any confusion, as I mentioned that I am currently visually observing the difference in shapes. Granted, a mean and MAD approach may be of some use, but I wanted to know if there was already an established way of describing what an EDF **looks like** in a few (preferably one) numbers, to facilitate automation.

Comment: The statistical and mathematical meanings of "shape" closely emulate the colloquial meaning. People say two figures have the same shape if they "look the same." This allows for the figures to have different locations and even different sizes. What we need to know is whether *you* consider two EDFs with different locations or scales to have the same "shape" or not. *E.g.*, consider a dataset of temperatures. Would you consider the EDF for the Celsius values of these temperatures to have the same shape as the EDF for the Fahrenheit values or not?

Comment: @whuber: You comment caused me to pause for thought. Actually, come to think of it when I am "eyeballing" the shapes, I am visually checking if they "look the same" as an expected/historical 'shape' (first check), and then checking if the locations and scales are within some (acceptable) threshold from the expected/historical values (check 2). If either check 1 or check 2 fail, then it raises a flag for further investigation as to why there is difference in shape (where shape in this case also encompasses location/scale).

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is uni-variate, then why not just do a KS test on the (centered, re scaled) vectors?

You can't use the associated `pvalues` (because the center and scale components 
have been determined by the [data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Test_with_estimated_parameters)) but the `D` statistics gives a relative measure of the distance between the two vectors (In a nutshell, it's simply the Chebychev  distance between the two CDF).

So, in `R`, it would be (assuming `x` and `y` are two vectors of potentially different lengths  (each vector contains one of the sample whose shape of the distribution  you want to compare).

For example, if $x\sim\mathcal{P}(\lambda)$ and $y\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$:

```
#two distributions with different shape
y<-rnorm(100,0,3)
x<-rpois(100,1)
x_s<-(x-median(x))/mad(x)
y_s<-(y-median(y))/mad(y)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
hist(y_s)
hist(x_s)
ks.test(x_s,y_s)
```

P.S. I left the original answer, because it seemed to be useful and frankly took me time to write. @Modo: let me know if it's better to remove it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if the problem is multivariate:

Given a cloud of points with $p$ by $p$ covariance matrix 
$\varSigma$, the shape matrix of $\varSigma$ is 
defined as $\Gamma = |\varSigma|^{-1/p}\varSigma$. 
It follows that always $|\Gamma|=1$, and we can
decompose the original matrix as 
$\varSigma = |\varSigma|^{1/p}\Gamma$.
The square root of this scalar factor,
$|\varSigma|^{1/2p}$, is called the scale component
of $\varSigma$.

The shape matrix of the estimated [scatter matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_matrix) S
is computed analogously as $G = |S|^{-1/p}S$, and
its scale component is $|S|^{1/2p}$.

The difference (distance) between two shape matrices
$G_1$ and $G_2$ can be defined as 
\begin{equation}
\mbox{D_s}(G_1,G_2) =
      \log\frac{\lambda_1(G^{-1/2}_{2} G_{1} G^{-1/2}_{2})}
               {\lambda_p(G^{-1/2}_{2} G_{1} G^{-1/2}_{2})} 
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_1\geq...\geq\lambda_p$ are the eigenvalues.

Comment: What is _p_ in your formulas? Is it the size of the square matrix (that is, number of variables for cov matrix and number of observations for scatter matrix)? Another thing, it'd be good if show how your formulas "degenerate" in univariate case, because the question author may have meant univariate distributions.

Comment: yes $p$ is the rank of the matrices (that's why there are $p$ eigen values). If the author meant univariate distributions, then my answer can't be used.

Comment: I see. So, _p_ is the number of positive eigenvalues, in both your cases, right? Your formulas are new to me. Could you please direct to the original source of them, to read more on the concept of "shape matrix"?

Comment: yes, both matrices need to be of same (and maximum) rank. I'm not sure i have a source handy --geometrically it is very intuitive-- but i will try to find one.

Comment: Sorry, I might miss something? Typically data have more observations _n_ than variables _m_. Then _nXn_ scatter matrix will have rank _m_ (like the cov matrix of the variables), not "full rank" _n_. So **what do you mean** saying "maximum rank"?

Comment: your m = my p. a n by p matrix with n>p has full rank. G_1 G_2 need to be both invertible.

Comment: If _n_ > _p_ _n_ X _n_ scatter matrix is not invertible, with zero |S|, and thus |S|^(-1/p) is illegal. That's what I cant't make out in your answer and why I'm asking.

Comment: OK let's get this from the beginning. a n by p, n>p matrix has a p by p invertible covariance matrix and this covariance matrix is invertible and i call it Sigma (or S for its sample estimate).

Comment: OK, let's. Have nXp (n>p) data matrix without colliniarities. Center its columns and then call this data C. C'C is "SSCP [sum-of-squares-and-cross-products] matrix of C" (while C'C/(n-1) is known as covariance matrix of C). C'C has p positive eigenvalues. Now, CC' (a SSCP of transposed C), a nXn matrix, is known as scatter matrix of C. It has same p positive eigenvalues as C'C had, the rest n-p eigenvalues being zero. CC' is hence singular, its determinant 0. How can you raise 0 to a negative power -1/p? Your answer seems to miss additional clarification.

Comment: Ok, now i see where is the problem. The text above only uses C'C. I had never heard CC' being referred to as a scatter matrix before. A scatter matrix is the sample estimator of the covariance matrix (the wikipedia page for scatter matrix seems to be on the same line fwiw). A scatter matrix is p by p (or m by m in your and wiki's notations).

Comment: All right. Admit your definition of scatter matrix as just SSCP matrix of centered data is more conventional. Still, I'd recomment you to explicitly define what you mean by "scatter matrix" in your answer.